# implementing search-view at the action-bar of the main activity not working probably

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, searchview, android-context

I have faced a problem when implementing searchview at the actionbar of the main activity .. where the main activity has bottom navigation menu with three fragments...

and the search view should work at each fragment ...

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {

```
private Boolean LoadContact = false ;
private BottomNavigationView navigationView ;
private String SearchText;
int page;

AllContactFrag allContactFrag = new AllContactFrag();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

  final Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
   setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

   toolbar.setTitle("Special Contact");


    navigationView =(BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigationView);

    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.frame, new SpecialContactFrag());
    ft.commit();
   // navigationView.setSelectedItemId();


    navigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

            int id = item.getItemId();
            switch (id)
            {
                case R.id.action_MyNotes:

                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putString("text",SearchText);
                    Fragment AllNotes = new NotesFrag();
                    AllNotes.setArguments(bundle);
                    FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                    FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
                    transaction.replace(R.id.frame,AllNotes);
                    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                    transaction.commit();

                    toolbar.setTitle("My Note");
                    return true;

                case R.id.action_AllContact:

                    Bundle bundle2 = new Bundle();
                    bundle2.putString("text",SearchText);
                    Fragment AlxlContact = new AllContactFrag();
                    AlxlContact.setArguments(bundle2);
                    FragmentManager xmanager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                    FragmentTransaction xtransaction = xmanager.beginTransaction();
                    xtransaction.replace(R.id.frame,AlxlContact);
                    xtransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                    xtransaction.commit();
                    toolbar.setTitle("Phone Contact");
                    return true;

                case R.id.action_Spec:
                    Fragment AlxxlContact = new SpecialContactFrag();
                    FragmentManager xxmanager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                    FragmentTransaction xxtransaction = xxmanager.beginTransaction();
                    xxtransaction.replace(R.id.frame,AlxxlContact);
                    xxtransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                    xxtransaction.commit();
                    toolbar.setTitle("Special Contact");
                    return true;

            }

            return true;
        }
    });

}



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager)getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
```

MenuItem menuItem =menu.findItem(R.id.search);
  SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menuItem.getActionView();
     searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

```
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
    return true;
}



@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();


}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {


    int id = navigationView.getSelectedItemId();

    switch (id)
    {
        case R.id.action_MyNotes:

            Fragment NoteFrgment = new NotesFrag();
            ((NotesFrag) NoteFrgment).onQueryTextSubmit(query);

        case R.id.action_AllContact:
            Fragment AllCont = new AllContactFrag();
            ((AllContactFrag) AllCont).onQueryTextSubmit(query);
            return true;
        case R.id.action_Spec :
            Fragment Spec = new SpecialContactFrag();
            ((SpecialContactFrag) Spec).onQueryTextSubmit(query);

    }

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

   // Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),newText,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    SearchText = newText ;

    int id = navigationView.getSelectedItemId();

    switch (id)
    {
        case R.id.action_MyNotes:

            Fragment NoteFrgment = new NotesFrag();
            ((NotesFrag) NoteFrgment).onQueryTextChange(newText);

        case R.id.action_AllContact:
                AllContactFrag AllCont = (AllContactFrag)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frame);
                ((AllContactFrag) AllCont).onQueryTextChange(newText);
            return true;
        case R.id.action_Spec :
            Fragment Spec = new SpecialContactFrag();

            ((SpecialContactFrag) Spec).onQueryTextChange(newText);

    }

    return true;
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

    allContactFrag.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

}

/*   public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {


    List<Fragment> fragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> fragmentListTitle = new ArrayList<>();


    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        if(LoadContact){
            return fragmentList.get(position);
        }else {
            return fragmentList.get(position);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return fragmentList.size();
    }

    public void AddFragment(Fragment fragment, String fragmentTitle)
    {
        fragmentList.add(fragment);
        fragmentListTitle.add(fragmentTitle);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return fragmentListTitle.get(position);
    }
}
*/
```

}

//

```
 @Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

   // Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),newText,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    SearchText = newText ;

    int id = navigationView.getSelectedItemId();

    switch (id)
    {
        case R.id.action_MyNotes:

            Fragment NoteFrgment = new NotesFrag();
            ((NotesFrag) NoteFrgment).onQueryTextChange(newText);

        case R.id.action_AllContact:
                AllContactFrag AllCont = (AllContactFrag)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frame);
                ((AllContactFrag) AllCont).onQueryTextChange(newText);
            return true;
        case R.id.action_Spec :
            Fragment Spec = new SpecialContactFrag();

            ((SpecialContactFrag) Spec).onQueryTextChange(newText);

    }

    return true;
}
```

// at the fragment

```
   @Override
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {

    Log.d("", "onQueryTextSubmit: ");
    search_list = new ArrayList<>();
    search_list.clear();

    Context context = getContext();
    db = new dbhandler(mcontext);
 phoneList = new ArrayList<>();
   phoneList = db.getAllPhoneContact();


    String name;
    contact contact  = new contact();
    for (int i = 0; i < phoneList.size(); i++)
    {
        contact = phoneList.get(i);
        name = phoneList.get(i).getName();
        if(name.contains(s))
        {
            search_list.add(contact);
        }
     }


    allConAdapter = new AllConAdapter(getActivity(),search_list, 0);

    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    recyclerView.setAdapter(allConAdapter);

    allConAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    return true ;

}

private Context mcontext;

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);

    mcontext = context ;
    Log.d("", "onAttach: ");
}
```

at the fragment at onQueryTextSubmit the context value becomes null so the app crashes because I want to read data from SQLite and context is null

Comment: `Context context = getContext();`, `db = new dbhandler(mcontext);` – You've apparently got two `Context` variables there. Are you `mcontext` is what you meant to use? You really shouldn't be keeping a `Context` field anyway. Just call `getContext()` as needed.

Comment: thanks @MikeM. but getcontext() also return null  so i  have used mcontext

Comment: We'll need to see how you're setting the `Fragment` as the `OnQueryTextListener` on that `SearchView`, and how you're transacting that `Fragment` into the `Activity`.

Comment: @MikeM. I have updated the post and added the main activity code

Comment: `Fragment NoteFrgment = new NotesFrag();` – That's your problem. You're instantiating new `Fragment`s right before calling `onQueryTextSubmit()` on them. Those `Fragment` instances are not the ones attached to your `Activity`, which is why they don't have access to a `Context`. If that's how you want to handle passing the query change down, then either keep track of those instances you create for the `FragmentTransaction`s above, or use one of the `FragmentManager#findFragmentBy*()` methods to get them from the `FragmentManager`.

Comment: thanks @MikeM.  then i should replace creating new instance by FragmentManager#findFragmentBy*() ...... Fragment NoteFrgment = FragmentManage.findFragmentBy*() ... i will check that